# Spring boot replace character "?" and "&"

Tags: spring-boot, replace

I have a url in String that with conditionals i add parameters. In the end i want to replace (if exists) the string "?&" by "?", but i recieve a error.

**My code:**

```
    String url =  this.baseUrl + "/test/customers/" + customerId;

    if(null != date || null != li|| null != direction) {
        url = url + "?";
    }

    if(null != date) {
        url = url + "date=" + date;
    }
    if(null != li) {
        url = url + "&li=" + li;
    }

    url = url + "&direction=" + direction;

    url = url.replaceAll("?&", "?");
```

**The error:**

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0
```

Comment: Try escaping the questionmark `\\?&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is reserved character for regexes, you need to escape them, try.

```
url = url.replaceAll("\\?&", "?");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
url = url.replaceAll("\\&", "");
```